# Перегрузка оператора присваивания в C++

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь умных людей. Нужно: Создать класс СТРОКА, реализующий текстовую строку. То есть хранит цепочку символов переменной длины, позволяет определить её длину, поддерживает операцию конкатенации и сравнения двух строк. Составить примеры использования и набор тестов.(Задание по варианту: Создать класс ВОСЬМЕРИЧНАЯ_СТРОКА.Добавить возможность заполнения значения строки из числа в двоичной системе). Задание было сделано, но преподавателю нужно добавить перегрузку оператора присваивания и как-то сделать проверку. Код программы прилагается. Основной файл - PROGA.cpp, дополнительный файл - String.h.
Файл PROGA.cpp:

```
#include "String.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Лабораторная работа №2"<<endl;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    getOctStr s("20000");
    getOctStr f("25000");
    cout << "Первая строка: ";
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << "Перевод из восьмеричной в двоичную систему счисления: ";
    cout << s-f << endl;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "Вторая строка: ";
    cout << f<< endl;
    cout << "Перевод из восьмеричной в двоичную систему счисления: ";
    cout << f - s << endl;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "Склеивание двух строк: ";
    s += f;
    cout << s << endl;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "Длина первой строки: ";
    cout << s.getLength() << endl;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "Длина второй строки: ";
    cout << f.getLength() << endl;
    cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "Строки равны - 1. Строки не равны - 0"<<endl;
    cout << (s == f) << endl;
        cout <<"------------------------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;

}

String::String()
{
    Str = 0;
    Length = 0;
}

String::String(const char* ptr)
    : Length(strlen(ptr)), Str(new char[Length + 1])
{
    strcpy(Str, ptr);
}

String::String(const String& t)
    : Length(strlen(t.Str)), Str(new char[Length + 1])
{
    strcpy(Str, t.Str);
}

String& String::operator += (const String& t)
{
    int newLength = Length + t.Length;
    char *newStr = new char[newLength + 1];
    strcpy(newStr, Str);
    strcat(newStr, t.Str);
    delete[] Str;
    Str = newStr;
    Length = newLength;
    return *this;
}

bool String::operator == (const String& t) const
{
    return Length == t.Length && strcmp(Str, t.Str) == 0;
}

bool String::operator != (const String& t) const
{
    return !(operator == (t));
}

bool String::is_empty() const
{
    return Str == 0 || Str[0] == '\0';
}

const char* String::getStr() const
{
    return Str;
}

int String::getLength() const
{
    return Length;
}

ostream & String::show(ostream & os) const
{
    return os << "\"" << (Str ? Str : "") << "\"";
}

String::~String()
{
    Length = 0;
    delete[] Str;
    Str = 0;
}

getOctStr::getOctStr() : String()
{ }

getOctStr::getOctStr(const char* ptr) : String(ptr)
{ }

getOctStr::getOctStr(const getOctStr& t) : String(t)
{ }

String getOctStr::operator - (const String& t) 
{
    const int MAX_BUF = 80;
    char buf[MAX_BUF];
    _ltoa(strtoll(Str, 0, 8), buf, 2);
    return String(buf);
}

getOctStr::~getOctStr()
{

}
```

Файл String.h:

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class String
{
protected:
    int Length;
    char* Str;
public:
    String();
    String(const char* ptr);
    String(const String& t);
    String& operator += (const String& t);
    bool operator == (const String& t) const;

    String& operator = (const String& t);
    if (this ==&t) {
        return *this;
    }
    Length = t.Length;
    return *this;

    bool operator != (const String& t) const;
    bool is_empty() const;
    const char* getStr() const;
    int getLength() const;

    ostream & show(ostream & os) const;
    friend ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const String & s)
    {
        return s.show(os);
    }

    ~String();
};

class getOctStr : public String
{
public:
    getOctStr();
    getOctStr(const char* ptr);
    getOctStr(const getOctStr& t);

    String operator - (const String& t);
    ~getOctStr();
};
```

Просто вообще не понятно как это сделать, а сделать нужно. Заранее спасибо за помощь всем кто подскажет. P.S. Буду очень благодарен готовому коду, т.к. я пробовал добавил в String.h строку:

```
String& operator = (String& t);
```

А в PROGA.cpp строки:

```
String& String::operator = (String& t)
{
    swap (Length, t.Length);
    swap (Str, t.Str);
    return *this;
}
```

На что мне сказали что swap вообще не используется, а по другому - никак не получается и все не работает. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы пишите `int a = 1, b = 2; a = b;` вы ожидаете что после присваивания `а` изменится значение `b`? Операция присваивания не должна менять свой аргумент.

Первый подход к решению вашей задачи: при присваивании освободить текущую строку, выделить память под новую строку и скопировать данные:

```
String& operator=(const String& t)
{ // аргумент не должен изменятся -> const
    delete[] Str;
    Length = t.Length;
    Str = new char[Length];
    strcpy(Str, t.Str);
    return *this;
}
```

Этот имеет недостатки, такие как: проблема безопасности исключений, необходимость проверки на присваивание самому себе. Лучшим подход будет использовать [copy-and-swap идиому](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-and-swap):

```
String& operator=(const String& t)
{
   String temp{t};
   std::swap(*this, temp);
   return *this;
}
```

[Больше об идиоме copy-and-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: Для copy & swap, имхо, лучше вместо `String& operator=(const String& t){String temp{t};` сделать `String &operator=(String temp){`. Тогда он будет еще и как move assignment работать...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен. @QypeR, `String& String::operator=` и реализацию.

Comment: @acade, Большое спасибо, то есть в файл PROGA.cpp мне нужно добавить выше указанные строки, а в файле String.h оставить строку String& operator = (String& t); Так? И если не так, то как?)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а я не согласен — это плохой способ. Нужны перемещения — добавляйте соответствующий оператор.

Comment: @ixSci Можно подробнее? Чем он хуже?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если вкратце, то это порождает плохой стиль и проблемы. Если подробно, то почитайте мою [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2018/07/30/value_vs_reference.aspx). Там я полностью раскрыл, что я об этом всём думаю :)

Comment: @ixSci Бегло прочитал. :) Делаю вывод, что *"[передача классов по значению] порождает плохой стиль и проблемы"* - это вы про передачу параметров в функции в общем случае. Конкретно для copy&swap это, насколько я понимаю, никаких проблем не создает (но сокращает код, и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/2752075) даже уверяют, что слегка улучшает производительность), так что здесь вы предлагаете передачу по константной ссылке для единообразия стиля кода. Правильно?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, если сильно упрощённо, то — да, правильно. Вы прекрасно знаете, что такое SO-driven development, и как куски кода отсюда становятся точными копиями кода в проектах. Потом это как раковая опухоль разлетается по другим частям, а нерадивые программисты (коих большинство) начинают использовать это везде. Кроме того, в статье есть примеры, когда передача по значению (даже в этой идиоме) будет сильно влиять на производительность. Про указанную ссылку я знаю, и с этим человек я не согласен.

Comment: @QypeR, в `String.h` оставляете только объявление, в cpp-файле пишите определение (реализацию) метода `operator=`. Проследите за идентичностью аргументов метода - `const String&` должно быть и при объявлении и при определении.